# fig.text in italic delete space in string how to avoid?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why does the below code delete space when printed on figure `fig` ?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
TestStr= "$* This is a Test$"
print(TestStr) # Returns : * This is a Test 
text = fig.text(0.30, 0.005, BoFaSpread,horizontalalignment='center', wrap=True)# Displays on fig : *ThisisaTest
```

Comment: Is this a matplotlib question, or some other library? Can you please add the appropriate tag so we have more context.

Comment: @CoryKramer this is matplotlib library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [`matplotlib.text.Text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) instances have [properties](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_props.html) that can be included when adding text to a figure. The one that can be used here is [`fontstyle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_fontstyle) (`style` also works)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 3))
testStr = "$* This is a Test$"
fig.text(0.5, 0.6, testStr, horizontalalignment='center')

testStr2 = "* This is a Test"  # don't need to include $ in the text
fig.text(0.5, 0.5, testStr2, horizontalalignment='center', fontstyle="italic") 
# can also use style="italic"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because it is rendered as `Markdown Math` or `Katex` as inline math block.
Following is syntax for inline math block in markdown: `$equation$`
`$* This is a Test$` in markdown will be `*ThisisaTest` hence there's no space.
You can use space as per markdown `\>` in your text. So you can do one of the following:

```
plt.title("$*This \> is \> Text*$") # \> will add space
plt.title("$\\it{This \> is \> Text}$") # \it is markdown function for italic text
```

And you can also passed keyword arg of `fontstyle="italic"` also

```
plt.title("This is Text", fontstyle="italic")
```

I hope this solved your issue.

Comment: hod do I correct it and get a italic text with space then please ?